# Display percentage on the Y axis

Tags: asp.net, charts

How to display Percentage on the Y-axis using a MS Chart Control. I want it to start from 0 and till 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?  The windows forms version has the same property names.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            <Points>
                <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="25" />
                <asp:DataPoint XValue="2" YValues="59" />
            </Points>
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Title="Percent">
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?